# What is the sum of digits in the unit place of all numbers

Tags: permutations, combinations, mathematica

What is the sum of digits in the unit place of all numbers formed using 1,2,3,4,5,6 taken all at a time without repeating any of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sum of digits in the unit place $$=(6-1)!(1+2+3+4+5+6)$$
$$=5! ~\times~21~=~120~\times~21~=~2520$$

---

**Explanation :**  Let us first choose the unit place as $~6~$, then the possible choice for other places are $~5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1~=~5!~=~120$.

Now if we choose the unit place as $~5~$, then the possible choice for other places are again  $~5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1~=~5!~=~120$.

Similarly, the others.

So the total sum of digits in the unit place of all numbers formed using $~1,~2,~3,~4,~5,~6~$ taken all at a time without repeating any of them $$~=(~6~\times~5!~)+(~5~\times~5!~)+(~4~\times~5!~)+(~3~\times ~5!~)+(~2~\times~5!~)+(~1~\times ~5!~)$$
$$=~5!~\times~(6+5+4+3+2+1)~$$$$=~120~\times~21~$$$$=~2520$$